# The universal property of pullback bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology

The universal property says the following: for any pair of maps $i: Z \to X$ and $j: Z \to E$ fitting into the following commuting diagram where $p: E \to B$ is a fiber bundle (by the way this is true for any Serre fibration but I am applying it to a fiber bundle)
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
  Z @>j>> E \\
  @ViVV @VVpV \\
  X @>f>> B
\end{CD}
there exists a unique map $\psi: Z \to X \times_B E$ which factors through $i, j$ as follows (sorry I don't know how to draw the diagonal arrow)
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
  Z @>j>> E \\
  @ViVV @AAA \\
  X @<<< X \times_B E
\end{CD}
where $X \times_B E \to X$ is defined by $(x,e) \mapsto x$ and $X \times_B E \to E$ is defined by $(x,e) \mapsto e$.

Now suppose $i: Z \to X$ is also a fiber bundle over $X$ thus $\psi: Z \to X \times_B E$ defines a bundle map.
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
  Z @>\psi>> X \times_B E \\
  @ViVV @VVV \\
  X @= X
\end{CD}
My question is: when is $\psi$ an isomorphism of bundles? i.e. when does $\psi$ have an inverse?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're looking for here.  Are you working in the category of topological spaces, and just asking for a concrete description of what a pullback in topological spaces is?  (Also, what do you mean by "fibration" exactly?  Everything you say makes perfect sense for arbitrary maps...)

Comment: @Eric: sorry for the confusion!  What I mean is fiber bundle.  I have revised the question statement to make it clear.

Comment: I think it is when $Z$ also has the universal property, with maps $i, j$

Comment: It's still unclear to me what sort of answer would be helpful to you.  Do you know how to concretely describe $X\times_B E$ as a subspace of $X\times E$?  The answer to your question is, "when $\psi$ is a homeomorphism", and you can write out exactly what that means concretely in terms of the definition of the underlying set and topology of $X\times_B E$, but that may or may not be illuminating...

Comment: @Eric: Do you mean the following Eric?  If $\psi$ induces the identity map on the base space and a homeomorphism on the fibers then $\psi$ defines a bundle isomorphism?  Actually I think this is the answer but I have difficulty in seeing $\psi$ induces a homeomorphism on the fibers.

Comment: I don't think it's true that if $\psi$ induces a homeomorphism on the fibers then it automatically induces a homeomorphism on the total space.  That would be saying that for any continuous family of homeomorphisms, the inverses are also a continuous family, which I don't think is true in general.

Comment: @Eric: I see. Sorry for the confusing.  I think I should ask more specific question than this.  This question is probably too general to reveal my confusion.